# Answering own question months later

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer, old-questions

I was digging through my activity history on the site when I came across a question I asked a while ago that never received an answer.

> [Segmentation fault during Laravel Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119568/segmentation-fault-during-laravel-migration/54930251#54930251)

I figured now that I've solved the problem, I should probably post an answer to my own question so it wasn't abandoned. However, after I posted the answer I realised it wasn't a particularly popular question and as it currently stands is 104 days old with little to no activity.

Should I have answered it, or just deleted it?

Comment: Related help-center: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Have you even found a random forum post from 2005 describing exactly the problem you had, with either zero replies or only a "nevermind, solved it"? Believe me, self-answering a question is always better, even if only one other person finds it useful within the next 1000 years.

Comment: @FabianRöling It's traditional to link to a relevant XKCD page if you can find one: [Wisdom of the Ancients](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: Please keep in mind that "segmentation fault when doing x" is a most often a bad title. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults) to know why - "segmentation fault" is basically like saying "bug".

Comment: @Lundin Great list, thanks! I've come across segfaults a couple of times in the past but didn't realise they were _that_ generic.

Comment: It's not even old, in my opinion. Answer a question from 2014 and call it old, sure, but not last November!

Comment: In the lifecycle of an SO question, I’d consider anything over 24hrs to be old/abandoned ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're *encouraged* to answer your own questions around here.  There's nothing poor about your question, from what I could tell, so I don't believe it's subject to anyone coming after it.

At best, you can now incorporate it into your code's documentation to explain why you chose to implement something in this fashion.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Ordinarily I wouldn't have worried about self-answering a question - I just wasn't sure due to its age.

Comment: Age doesn't matter here, @Lewis. Only questions and answers.

Comment: @Lewis the one thing I will say to be careful about is if you come here with a "I got this great answer I want to post, so I'll write a question for it". In these circumstances, the question has to be up to our standards as well. You won't be allowed to post a garbage question just to be able to have the world's best answer on it. Outside of that consideration, the sky is the limit :)

Comment: Someday, someone is going to need that information and you've just saved them a big problem.  May you get a few votes from it!